# Need browsers refresh to get data displayed after user Login in react using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I enter correct credentials it logs me in and takes me to the dashboard page.
In the dashboard page, on the dashboard page in parent component of the page, I have dispatched the action to fetch the data using useeffect() and in the child component of that page I am accessing the state using mapStateToProps but when I go to the dashboard page I get blank data, and when I refresh browser page I am able to see the data.

This is My Login Action

```
export const loginAction = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_LOAD, payload: '' })
        Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/shopuser/auth/login", data)
            .then((resp) => {
                dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FETCH, payload: resp.data.token })
                localStorage.setItem("tkn", resp.data.token)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                dispatch({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, payload: 'Error occured.' })
            })
    }
}
```

This is my login reducer

```
import { LOGIN_LOAD, LOGIN_FETCH, LOGIN_ERROR, LOGOUT } from "../actions/authActions";

const initialState = {
    isAuth: false,
    isLoading: false,
    token: '',
    loginError: ''
}

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case LOGIN_FETCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuth: true,
                isLoading: false,
                token: action.payload
            }
        case LOGIN_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                loginError: action.payload
            }
        case LOGOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                token: action.payload,
                isAuth: false,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default authReducer
```

Dashboard Action page

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}

export const getCurrentOrdersAction = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDERS_LOAD })
        Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/shopuser/order/orders', { headers })
            .then((resp) => {
                dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDERS_FETCH, payload: resp.data.orders })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                dispatch({
                    type: CURRENT_ORDERS_ERROR,
                    payload: "Unable to get data. Try again.",
                })
        });
    };
};
```

Dashboard Reducer

```
import {
    CURRENT_ORDERS_LOAD,
    CURRENT_ORDERS_FETCH,
    CURRENT_ORDERS_ERROR,
  } from "../actions/dashboardActions";

  const initialState = {
    currentOrders: [],
    error: "",
    isLoading: false,
  };

  const dashboardReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === CURRENT_ORDERS_LOAD) {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    }
    if (action.type === CURRENT_ORDERS_FETCH) {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        currentOrders: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };
    }
    if (action.type === CURRENT_ORDERS_ERROR) {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    }else{
        return state
    }
  };


  export default dashboardReducer
```

Dashboard dispatch action using useeffect

```
  const { getCurrentOrders } = props

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentOrders()
  }, [getCurrentOrders])

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getCurrentOrders: () => dispatch(getCurrentOrdersAction())
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Page where I am showing Data and consuming state

```
{props.currentOrdersData && props.currentOrdersData.map((data, index) => (
        <ExpansionPanel key={index} expanded={expanded === data.orderID} onChange={handleChange(data.orderID)} className={classes.newSection}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          >
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Order ID: #{data.orderID}</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <Grid container justify="space-between">
              <Grid item>
                <Link to="/shop/order" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                  <Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary">
                    View Order
                </Button>
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentOrdersData: state.dashboard.currentOrders
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CurrentOrders)
```

And finally the HOC for redirecting after login

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export default (OriginalComponent) => {
  class MixedComponent extends Component {

    preventLogin() {
      this.props.isAuthenticated && this.props.token
        && this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.preventLogin()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.preventLogin()
    }

    render() {
      return <OriginalComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuth,
      token: state.auth.token,
    };
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(MixedComponent);
};
```

Have I made any rendering mistake?

Comment: Can someone pls ANS I need it

Comment: inside the dashboard action, u r gettign token from the localStorage right?

Comment: yess. I am getting it as ive provided headers too @gdh

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting `token` after login inside the `dashboardActions.js` ? please check network call if its getting data from API or not, right after the login

Comment: I am getting `message: "Invalid Token..."
status: "error"` this right after login click

Comment: And after reload I get proper data @VivekDoshi

Comment: @SagarChavan, so the issue is with fetching token

Comment: soo how can I get it in the first go ? @VivekDoshi

Comment: I think @gdh has already figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. You need to put the lines of code to get the token from the localStorage INSIDE the `getCurrentOrdersAction` action(i.e. inside the dispatch). The issue is that you are using blank token in the action due to closure.

```js
export const getCurrentOrdersAction = () => {

  return (dispatch) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("tkn"); //<-----get the token here.

    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    };
    dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDERS_LOAD });
    Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/shopuser/order/orders", { headers })
      .then((resp) => {
        dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDERS_FETCH, payload: resp.data.orders });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({
          type: CURRENT_ORDERS_ERROR,
          payload: "Unable to get data. Try again.",
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: I tried. But same results. Getting data after I refresh browser  @gdh

Comment: i see, let me have another look at your code.. is it possible to put your code in sandbox? or do you have any repo?

Comment: and also when I use any other API which does not need authentication I am able to fetch it in first go without refreshing the browser.

Comment: for now, take the token from the store...it should fix ur issue....

Comment: 1st param in your action is dispatch and 2nd param is `getState` .. .access token from it and use it in `getCurrentOrdersAction`

Comment: do `localStorage.getItem("tkn");` inside the dispatch so that you will surely have the access to the token.

Comment: Also can u pls tell me.
sometimes when I get the data I get multiple console.log statements for a single dispatch.
is this dispatching problem?

Comment: Sorry I am new to react